# How can I compare two arrays of objects and add new key to an objects in the second array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm

Given the following arrays and I'm asked to compare both arrays and return filtered array two with elements found in array one:

```
const array1 = [
  { name: "Jack",      age: 54, title: "IT Engineer" },
  { name: "Josephine", age: 54, title: "chef"        },
  { name: "Cortez",    age: 34, title: "driver"      }
];

const array2 = [
  { name: "Alex",     age: 24,                      },
  { name: "Janvier",  age: 24, title: "IT Engineer" }
];
```

The expected output is a new array that must verify if **array two** elements don't involve in **array one**

if array two-dot name is equal to array one dot name  and array two doesn't have a **key** called **title** then

add **title key** in **array two** and set its value as **'none'**;

the expected output should look like this:

```
const result =  [
  { name: "Alex",   age: 24, title: "none"        },
  { name: "Arsene", age: 24, title: "IT Engineer" }
];
```

Comment: Are they in the same order, the items on array1 and array2?

Comment: Where does "Arsene" come from?  It's not in either input sample.

Comment: Just checked, your new input arrays, it does't change the code I've provided. I think the input samples are wrong, could you provide us with the proper input sample, or atleast communicate more clearly the criteria ?

Answer (score 2):

Your two arrays don't correspond to a useful output based on your requirements

Stating them a bit clearer

1. If a value of the property `name` in `array2` is not any of the values of the array elements of `array1`
   then do not add the `array2` element to the new array
2. If the value of the property `name` in `array2` is in `array1` AND the array element doesn't have the property title, add this to the array element.

Based on that criteria, you will get an empty array based on your arrays `array1` and `array2`.

```
const array1 = [
  { name: "Jack",      age: 54, title: "IT Engineer" },
  { name: "Josephine", age: 54, title: "chef"        },
  { name: "Cortez",    age: 34, title: "driver"      }
];

const array2 = [
  { name: "Alex",     age: 24,                      },
  { name: "Janvier",  age: 24, title: "IT Engineer" }
];

const array1_Values = array1.map(elem => elem.name);
const newArray = array2.filter(elem => {
  if (array1_Values.includes(elem.name) && !elem.hasOwnProperty('title')) {
    elem.title = 'none';
    return elem;
  } 
})

console.log(newArray); // Prints [] to console
```

Answer (score 0):

To loop that we first need to loop the first array then find element with title in the second array and add the JSON key we want to add as well

```
array1.map(elem => {
       const arr2WithTitle = arr2.find((data)=>data.name === elem.name);
         return arr2WithTitle.title ? data.title =arr2WithTitle.title: arr2WithTitle.title = "none"
     
    })
```